# Best way to manage a Web App-wide overlay and progress widget using Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to port a web application from pure jQuery to AngularJS and I ran across a widget that is used to show progress throughout the web application process. The widget is just a pop-up `<div>` with a partially transparent overlay behind it to "dim" the background web page. This effect is used all over the web now and I want to convert this widget into some kind of Angular directive or service of some type.

I was wondering if this kind of functionality would best be achieved using a Directive or a Service?

Right now, the widget is being inserted and removed from the DOM using this Module Pattern object.

```
WEBSITE.utils.overlay = function ($) {
    var _cover;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        _cover = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'cover').prependTo($('body'));
    });
    return {
        show: function () {
            $(_cover).addClass('show');
            $('html,body').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
            return _cover;
        },
        destroy: function () {
            $('html,body').unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll');
            $(_cover).removeClass('show');
        }
    }
} (jQuery);
```

As you can see, the widget is fairly simple and I want to make it available so that the HTML within the widget can be easily modified as well.  The most simple approach I was thinking could be to create a global Directive like:

```
<progressbar>Here is some text that I want displayed</progressbar>
```

So would creating a directive and just modifying the text within the controller be the best way to get this functionality? Or should I use something like a service to get it?

Comment: Directive is definitely the way to, this deals with DOM manipulation - you would most likely also want this to be callable from the controller (make a data call = start progress, finish = end progress) - I say directive with a `scope` method that makes it callable from the controller

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try it out and see what I get at least

Comment: You may also want to look into a provider - that way you could inject it into the controllers that need it, and just call it like that

Comment: I am not sure it is the best approach, but I usually use both a directive and a service. I call one of service's methods, passing the necessary parameters, and it uses a directive to show the widget. (It's more complex than it sounds, especially since you'd want to interract with the widget and change it's state, but once comleted it's a very useful and highly re-usable feature.)

Answer (score 1):

The "App-wide" part of your description points to implementing (at least part of) your widget using an angular service.  The HTML and behavior of the widget itself would probably best be implemented as a directive.

Something like this maybe?

Widget components:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
// the components of the widget
//model
.service('progressWidget',function($document){
    var _loadingMessage = "";
    var _visible = false;
    return {
        show: function(loadingMessage){
            _loadingMessage = loadingMessage;
            _visible = true;
        },
        hide: function(){
            _visible = false;
        },
        isVisible: function(){
            return _visible;
        },
        getLoadingMessage: function(){
            return _loadingMessage;
        }
    };
})
//view
.directive('progressWidget',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope: {
            loadingMessage: '=progressWidget'
        },
        link: function(scope){
            console.log(scope);
        },
        template: ['<div class="panel panel-default">'
                  ,'    <div class="panel-heading">'
                  ,'        <h3 class="panel-title">Loading...</h3>'
                  ,'    </div>'
                  ,'    <div class="panel-body">'
                  ,'        <div class="row">'
                  ,'        <p class="lead text-center">{{loadingMessage}}</p>'
                  ,'            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">'
                  ,'                <div class="progress progress-striped active">'
                  ,'                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 100%"></div>'
                  ,'                </div>'
                  ,'            </div>'
                  ,'        </div>'
                  ,'            <p class="text-center">Please wait</p>'
                  ,'    </div>'
                  ,'</div>'
                  ].join('')

    };
})
//controller
.controller('widgetHelperController',function($scope,progressWidget){
    $scope.widget = progressWidget;    
})
```

Consumer controllers:

```
.controller('myController',function($scope,progressWidget){
    $scope.clear = progressWidget.hide;
    $scope.validateTransaction = progressWidget.show.bind(null,
        'Your transaction is being validated');
    $scope.runBackgroundCheck = progressWidget.show.bind(null,
        'Running the background check');
})
.controller('myOtherController',function($scope,progressWidget){
    $scope.clear = progressWidget.hide;
    $scope.orderPizza = progressWidget.show.bind(null,
        'Your pizza order is being processed');
    $scope.issueWarrant = progressWidget.show.bind(null,
        'Your warrant is being issued');
})
```

And a little stub to put somewhere in your application template:

```
<div ng-controller="widgetHelperController">
    <div ng-if="widget.isVisible()" progress-widget="widget.getLoadingMessage()"></div>    
</div>
```

See this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/F4YN7/